# More voltage through USB ports

Tags: electrical-engineering

**What I want to build:**

So I have an AMD Wraith cooler. And I want to put it on my desk.

I managed to connect the coolers power input (12v fan header) to an USB port. And it runs on 5V.
I don't want the cooler to spin so i disconnected the fans.

**Problem:**

I don't have enough voltage for the RGB of the fans, the blue color is barely visible. Ring and logo work fine.

**Question:**

Can I connect to the cooler's power input 2 USBs? That would give the cooler 10V?

Problem is that one USB will connect to another USB... I think this might be a problem...
I don't really know...

Thank you!

Comment: You could try a better USB power supply that can deliver more watts.

Comment: Had a Samsung battery that could deliver 12V, but it never does... Maybe the battery and device communicate and request 12V... I don't know... But I got some 4 xVarta AA 12V NiMH batteries and I will link them to the cooler fan... Thank you for the idea!

Comment: I’m not talking about volts, I’m talking about amps. Some USB ports can only deliver 1 or 2 amps at 5volts. Others can deliver 3 or more amps. More Amps means more power at the same voltage.

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand now. I will look more into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I connect to the cooler's power input 2 USBs? That would give the cooler 10V?

No. Both ports are fed from the same 5 V power supply so their common pins are connected. Connecting the +5 V of one port to the ground of the other will short-circuit the first port.

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sense. :D